# Regarding ValueError: NaTType does not support strftime

Tags: dataframe, datetime, strftime

My dataframe has 2 levels for columns and I need to convert my column level[1] from datetime into strings but columns headers have some 'NaT's and hence my strftime function is failing.

```
df.columns=['a','b','d','d']+[x.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') for x in df.columns.levels[1][:-1]]
```

This gives me error that

```
ValueError: NaTType does not support strftime
```

Based on discussions on similar topic, I tried using

```
[x.datetime.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') for x in df.columns.levels[1][:-1]]
```

but then I get an error saying

```
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Is there anything that I am missing. Please help.
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition when converting with:

```
[ x.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') if not pd.isnull(x) else "01-01-1970" \
  for x in df.columns.levels[1][:-1]]
```